# How do you fry a fat, uneven salmon filet?

Tags: frying, fish, salmon

I can nail a decent medium rare salmon filet. But today the salmon I have bought turned out to be really fat - like 2 inches in height. Its sides have very steep slopes so its bound to cook unevenly.

I can manage a 1 inch high salmon filet, but 2 inches seem both too much and too uneven. What do you do?

Answer (score 2):

Bake it in the oven instead.

Start in a frying pan to sear the skin and put in a pre-heated oven for 15-20 minutes.

Be careful to get the fish out of the fridge for 10, 20 minutes before cooking it so that its temperature is not too cold so that it cooks more evenly.

Can't you slice the filet to make 2 1-in filet ?

Comment: You wouldn't have the skin on the second filet to keep it together if you cut them into 2 1 inch filets

Comment: yes, you are right.

Comment: @Max Usually best to edit your answer if someone points something like that out. (If the comments no longer make sense at that point, you can flag them as obsolete and we mods will clean them up for you.)